# Unable to locate package PySide2

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to using my Raspberry Pi and I installed qtcreator on it and tried to install PySide2 using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install PySide2
```

I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package PySide2
```

I'm running Python 3.9.2 on a 64 bit version of Raspbian on a 4 generation Raspberry Pi.

Is this the wrong command to install PySide2 ?

Here's a screen shot of the error I get when trying to use:

```
pip3 install PySide2
```

[image]

Comment: What OS and OS version are you running? What version of Python are you using and how was it installed? What is the exact error message you are receiving? Please edit your question and add the answers to these questions.

Comment: I added the details on the Python version and version of Raspberry Pi and OS version to the post. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Have you tried installing via pip? pip install PySide2 or pip3 install PySide2.

Comment: Using pip or pip3 comes back with: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2.
Maybe it's not supported any more? Maybe there's another supported version for Raspberry Pi? pip and pip3 looks for it at pypi.org and pinwheels.org before the error is displayed.

Comment: You could try building from source. Can you install anything via apt? such as sudo apt install tmux?

Comment: Yes. I used apt to just install scrot so I can update the post with a screen shot of the error I was getting with pip: sudo apt-get install scrot

Comment: From what I read online, building it from source is very difficult. Do you know of anyone who posted it up somewhere and a way I can install it?